# Accessing list positions inside functions like map in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have just tried rewriting some code, originally a short Javascript function, in Haskell. The original has 2 nested loops and the inner loop contains a check for equality against both loop counters:

```
function f(x, points){
  var i, j;
  var n = points.length;
  var result = 0;

  for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    var xprod = 1;
    for(j=0; j<n; j++){
      if(j != i){
        xprod *= (x - points[j][0]);
      }
    }
    result += points[i][1] * xprod;
  }
  return result;
}
```

I was hoping to be able to simplify it in Haskell, but I couldn't figure out how get hold of the i and j values without effectively writing out every step of the original recursively. In Javascript Array.map passes the list position into the callback function as the second parameter, but it seems that map in Haskell doesn't do this. My current Haskell version looks awful to me as I'm passing in 2 copies of the array (one for each loop):

```
xproduct :: Int -> Int -> Double -> [(Double,Double)] -> Double
xproduct _ _ _ [] = 1       
xproduct i j x (pt:todo) 
  | i == j =  (xproduct i (j+1) x todo) 
  | otherwise = (xproduct i (j+1) x todo) * (x - (fst pt))

solvestep :: Int -> Double -> [(Double,Double)] -> [(Double,Double)] -> Double 
solvestep _ _ _ [] = 0
solvestep i x pts (pt:todo) = ((snd pt) * xprod) + (solvestep (i+1) x pts todo)
  where xprod = xproduct i 0 x pts

solve :: Double -> [(Double,Double)] -> Double
solve x points = solvestep 0 x points points
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I generally avoid using any indices at all, if possible. In this case, what you're really working with is: any one element of the list with *all the other* elements. No need to express that with index comparison, instead write a function that will give you a suitable look into the list:

```
pickouts :: [a] -> [(a,[a])]
pickouts [] = []
pickouts (x:xs) = (x,xs) : (second (x:) <$> pickouts xs)
```

Then, the actual computation becomes just

```
f :: Double -> [(Double,Double)] -> Double
f x points = sum [q * product [x-p | (p,_)<-ps] | ((_,q),ps) <- pickouts points]
```